# PHPStan - change type of constructor parameter

Tags: static-analysis, phpstan

When running PHPStan on my codebase I get the error:

```
Parameter #2 $credentials of class Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken constructor expects string, null given.
```

This is because the constructor's docblock only specifies a string as valid type. But when you check the `eraseCredentials()` method, it seems that `null` also is a valid value for `$credentials`.

Now I want to instruct PHPStan that the type of the `$credentials` parameter is `string|null` as opposed to `string`.

I think I would need an implementation of `MethodsClassReflectionExtension` to do that. But when I register this it does not seem to get called for the right class.

My current implementation:

```
class UsernamePasswordToken implements MethodsClassReflectionExtension
{
    public function hasMethod(ClassReflection $classReflection, string $methodName): bool
    {
        if ($classReflection->getName()===\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::class) {
            var_dump(__FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ . ' :: ' . __METHOD__);die();
        }
        if ($methodName === '__construct' && $classReflection->getName() === UsernamePasswordTokenClass::class) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getMethod(ClassReflection $classReflection, string $methodName): MethodReflection
    {
        var_dump(__FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ . ' :: ' . __METHOD__);die();
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to make PHPStan understand that the `$credentials` property accepts both `string` and `null` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use extensions to override information about existing method. There's currently no way to convince PHPStan that a method has a different signature than the one in the code.

I'm a little bit confused by the reported error, because [UsernamePasswordToken](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.php) currently accepts `mixed` (meaning anything) as the type of `$credentials`. So your issue can go away just by upgrading Symfony (not sure to which version). And also I don't know what you mean by referencing the `eraseCredentials` method.

If you need to solve a similar issue and the parameter documentation is wrong even in the recent version of your dependency, you have currently two options:

1) Send a PR to the depedency that fixes their typehint or phpDoc.
2) Write a regexp for `ignoreErrors` (see [README](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan#ignore-error-messages-with-regular-expresions)) that ignores this issue.

In the future, there will be a third option. I'm planning to enable overriding 3rd party types by offering configuration options to do that.

Comment: Apparantly I had an old version of `symfony/security-core`. I updated it and now this error went away. I have still several instances of this problem left though. I have added ignore rules for those cases.